# In Figma, how do I export PNGs all with the same dimensions?

Tags: figma

I'm trying to export 3 differently-sized images as PNGs in Figma. I'd like each image to be contained in the same sized box when exported.

Some things I've tried:

- Adding a transparent rectangle with the size I want behind them.
- Adding a frame to each with the size I want.
- Using a group with the dimensions I want.
- Switching the frame to an auto-layout and setting the dimensions.

Attached is a screenshot of the frame wrapping one of the images.

[image: frame wrapping image with 607 x 770 pixel dimensions]

Example of all three images exported at 1.5x. I'd expected all three images to have the same dimensions.

[image: image dimensions exported at 1.5x]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this by wrapping my image in a frame and selecting the "Clip content" box in the frame settings.

[image: Clip content selected]

Now all three images have the same dimensions when exported.

[image]